# Am I able to bypass Jenkins tsl errors and continue with the build?

Tags: jenkins, npm

My question is related to Jenkins and linting errors.

When I run `npm run build` locally on my machine, I am successfully able to build my code base, without any errors.

However, when I run `npm run build` on Jenkins, the job FAILS due to linting errors, usually related to case sensitive issues, and varialbes of type any.

Here is an example:

`ERROR in {jenkins-path-to-tsx-file}
[tsl] ERROR in {jenkins-path-to-tsx-file}(3,35)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './ResetPasswordForm'.`

And

`ERROR in {jenkins-path-to-tsx-file}
[tsl] ERROR in {jenkins-path-to-tsx-file}(38,29)
      TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

I understand how to fix these errors in my application code to remove these errors.

My question is, am I able to stop the build failing due to these errors, and display them as warnings, or continue building the Jenkins job despite the errors above?

Comment: Does your project build on Jenkins if you disable linting altogether? Since not finding modules is a pretty severe error, it might fail after linting anyway, so you would have to fix it.
What kind of project is it? (Frameworks, ...)

Comment: @awaigand  I'm not sure how to disable the linting, as it seems to be done automatically.  This is a TypeScript project.